# Is the modulo operation a standard mathematical operation which actually means Euclidean division?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I was having this long discussion with a colleague as to whether the [Modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is a standard mathematical operation or not.

He insisted the programming languages don't have a [defined standard for the sign of the operation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/226164/62793) because it's not mathematical standard which dictates Euclidean division and therefore they were free to decide. Upon showing the point mentioned in Wikipedia which stated:

> In mathematics the result of the modulo operation is the remainder of the Euclidean division.

he said it's just a Wikipedia article not a standard and that the immediately following statement:

> However, other conventions are possible.

actually point to the fact that the operation is not a standard meaning Euclidean division.

Is the modulo operation a standard mathematical operation?

As a side question, how are standards defined in mathematics?

Comment: In maths, mod isn't used as an operator. It's an equivalence relation. So $7\equiv 3$ (mod $4$) and $7\equiv -1$ (mod $4$) or even $7\equiv 15$ (mod $4$) are all correct (and equivalent) statements.

Comment: ... and we don't actually use division in the process. Thus a statement like $a\equiv b\pmod 0$ has a perfectly defined meaning (namely that $a=b$), whereas your average CPU will shout division by zero when you try to compute `a % 0`.